# Calculated property set as optional get as non optional

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna create calculated property:

```
  var status: Int? {
    get { return _status }
    set {
      if let newValue = newValue {
        updateStatus(newValue: newValue)
      }
    }
  }
```

Where _status is :Int.
But I wanna geting at non-optional.

`user.status` without `!`

How the best way for do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a single property, because the get and set accessors need to type-match exactly. The closest you can come is a property wrapper, using `$` to do all of your setting.

```swift
@objc final class ObjectiveCObject: NSObject {
  var status = 0
}

struct StatusThingy {
  @DefaultWhenSetToNil var status: Int
}

let object = ObjectiveCObject()

let thingy = StatusThingy(
  status: .init(
    wrappedValue: .init { object.status } set: { object.status = $0 },
    default: object.status
  )
)

thingy.status // 0
thingy.$status = 1
thingy.status // 1
thingy.$status = nil
thingy.status // 0
```

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct DefaultWhenSetToNil<Value> {
  @Computed private(set) var wrappedValue: Value
  let `default`: Value

  var projectedValue: Value? {
    get { wrappedValue }
    nonmutating set { wrappedValue = newValue ?? `default` }
  }
}
```

```swift
/// A workaround for limitations of Swift's computed properties.
///
/// Limitations of Swift's computed property accessors:
/// 1. They are not mutable.
/// 2. They cannot be referenced as closures.
@propertyWrapper public struct Computed<Value> {
  public typealias Get = () -> Value
  public typealias Set = (Value) -> Void

  public init(
    get: @escaping Get,
    set: @escaping Set
  ) {
    self.get = get
    self.set = set
  }

  public var get: Get
  public var set: Set

  public var wrappedValue: Value {
    get { get() }
    nonmutating set { set(newValue) }
  }

  public var projectedValue: Self {
    get { self }
    set { self = newValue }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But why we shouldn't use it with exclamation mark? Could you explain it more, please? Maybe simple example where it will not work?

Comment: The return type of an implicitly unwrapped optional property is still an optional unless you explicitly type it when assigning to a variable, so you're going to have to do that, or use `!`, at some point, which you said you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Yes, ok. I think your answer more correctly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a default value like this

```
    private var _status: Int

    var status: Int! {
    get {
        return _status
    }
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            _status = newValue
        } else {
            _status = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the computed property an implicitly unwrapped optional?  The backing variable is not optional, so there is no need for the computed property to be optional.

Comment: @Paulw11 in my case _status is objc property and can't be optional. But setter should. For silent get warning about call optional we mark it like !. Be because we sure about no nil will never be returned.
If we set as  `var status: Int?` we will, should to wrap all getter request like: `user.status ?? 0`
And  `Int?` And `Int!` both is optionals.

Comment: @Paulw11 just for guard from nils in one place instead each setter call.